# Extend image 100% width beyond parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to extend these slideshow images beyond the parent element of the container which is 1024px. I've tried setting max-width:100% to both the img selector, inline styling,etc. I can easily get the image 100% width but then that also sets the container to 100% which I don't want. I want the container element to remain the same, but only make the image 100% of the container.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/schermerb/tK6H9/1/

```
<div class="main-inner">
    <div class="slider">
        <img alt="" src="images/slide1.jpg" />
        <img alt="" src="images/slide2.jpg" />
        <img alt="" src="images/slide4.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>

.main-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 475px;
    margin: auto;
}
.slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 475px;
}
.slider img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 475px;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
/* SLIDER CONTAINER */
 .slider-container {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 475px;
}
.previous-btn, .next-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: auto;
}
.previous-btn {
    left: 0;
    background: url(images/prev.png);
}
.next-btn {
    background: url(images/next.png);
    right: 0;
}
/* PAGiNATION */
 .pagination {
    position: absolute;
    top: 450px;
    right: 6px;
    margin: auto 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.pagination li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
.pagination li a {
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #fff;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: block;
    opacity: 10;
}
.pagination li.current-pagination a, .pagination li a:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
    background: #00a1f1;
}
```

Comment: If the parent element is a fixed width, is there some reason you can't just set `.slider img` to `width: 2048px;`?

Comment: No, because it still inherits the parent element width. I need a way for it to completely ignore that width yet retain the container width so container elements don't extend 100% as well.

Comment: Either I didnt understand what you are asking, or you have your stuff all wrong here... Are you asking to set the img size to 100% of the actual .jpg file? That 100% you are setting is "100% of the parent size"

Comment: Ideally, yes. I have the container which is 1024px it contains the pagination/controls. I want the images of the slide container to be 100% of the screen. I want the content in the slide container to remain 1024px.

Comment: That can't be done the way you want. When you set something to width/height: 100%, it will take it as "100% of whatever is above me with a defined width/height". You will need to either set the width of `.slider img` as some value in pixels (e.g. 2048px) or have some javascript to get the actual `window.width()`

Comment: Can you update your fiddle with the actual images in question?

Comment: You'll need to separate the pagination/controls and the images if you want them to be different sizes. Then, set the controls to 1024px and the images to 100% of the screen.

Comment: Also, do you want the images to show as their full size, or to get cut off by the container, just showing portion of the size?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tK6H9/3/ see if this is somewhat what you want... I'm heading home now, will check back once I get there :)

Comment: No, I want the images to extend beyond the actual value of the container. The images are 1900px right now, but are cut off at 1024px because of the container.

Comment: Whats the height of those images? And I suppose you want them centered, right?

Comment: This? http://jsfiddle.net/tK6H9/5/

Comment: Image still retains to parent value.

Comment: What do you mean by "retain parent value"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38939/discussion-between-giovanni-silveira-and-blake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so some small changes were done.

To prevent scrolling from the big image:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

To have the image the size you want:

```
.slider img {
    width: 1900px;
    height: 475px;
    left:50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: -950px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

And finally, add `overflow:visible;` on `.slider`, to avoid the images from being cut on your prototype.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tK6H9/6/)**